# Coalesce with group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these two tables:

users (this has an updated_at column) and user_updates (this has a foreign key user_id to users and a created_at column)

I want to find the latest user update for user so I have this:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(user_updates.created_at) as last_update
FROM user_updates
WHERE user_id IN (<user_id>)
GROUP BY 1
```

However, sometimes the user_update won't have `created_at` so I need to do a COALLESCE with the `users.updated_at`. I have tried this:

```
SELECT user_id, COALESCE(MAX(user_updates.created_at), users.updated_at) as last_update
FROM user_updates
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = user_updates.user_id
WHERE user_id IN (<user_id>)
GROUP BY 1
```

But Postgres is complaining saying that: "column "users.updated_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

How can I fix this?

Comment: Uh, what's in `user_updates` that's not in `users`?  Is it extra information, or is `user_updates` the history table for `users`?  If so, shouldn't `users` be the most up-to-date information...?

Comment: Some info that is not in `users`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `COALESCE` inside the `MAX` function:

```
SELECT  user_id, 
        MAX(COALESCE(user_updates.created_at,users.updated_at)) as last_update
FROM user_updates
INNER JOIN users 
    ON users.id = user_updates.user_id
WHERE user_id IN (<user_id>)
GROUP BY user_id
;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is actually not fixing the issue that I'm having :(. Some times I don't even have `user_updates` for a user, and this won't return anything. How can I change it?

Comment: so, when you don't have a `user_update`, what value should it show?